# using switch buttons in android application

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I am using this code for my android application. but the problem in this code that it works perfectly while installing on emulator. as soon as i try to install this in my mobile it's installed but while opening the applcation it displays the error message as application not responding. And i need to use switch buttons.Is there any other way to use it?

```
    switch1= (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

    switch1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {  
             if(switch1.getText().toString().equals("On"))
             {
                String message = "t030s005n123456";                 

                sendSMS(phoneNo, message);          
             }

             else if(switch1.getText().toString().equals("Off"))
             {
                String message = "notn123456";                 

                sendSMS(phoneNo, message);  
             }
        }
    });
```

Comment: PLEASE PASTE THE LOGCAT!

Comment: which version installed in that device... switch is working from android 4.0(API level 14). Even u set minimum version in manifest file it is installed but show error while running the application if device is less version than 4.0.

Comment: my device is version 4.0.3(API leve 15)

Comment: error message is "the application has stopped unexpectedly. please try again!"

Comment: But in your post you say it displays ANR(Android Not responding) message.. Which one is it..?

Comment: which line is mentioned in the logcat error?

Comment: 05-19 22:01:06.808: I/Process(588): Sending signal. PID: 588 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

Call `sendSms()` method in a new thread. This is just a quick fix.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        void run() {
            sendSms();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Alternately, you might want to show progress dialog and do other stuff on completion of the sending task. In such case use a `AsyncTask`. Google for good examples.

Answer (score 0):

switch1= (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

```
Api levels lesser than 14 does not support your switch1 obj must be null.. 
place if(switch1!=null)
{
//click listener
}
```

Also make sure your device is upgraded to api level 14 `ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH`.

**As the switch widget are from api level 14.**